# Google Chrome Toolbar breaking website layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I have an issue with Google Chrome: 19.0.1084.52 m when I have the [Ask Toolbar](http://about.ask.com/apn/toolbar/docs/default/faq/en/chrome/chrome.html#na1) installed
it breaks the website layout.

See print screen:
[image]

Is it usual behaviour that toolbars in Chrome would effect the website?

EDIT: I guess I should wrap everything inside a `<div>` and move the background-image from the `<body>` although is there a better option without adding this extra markup?

[Website link](http://supremebeing.co.za)

Comment: i won't think this is because of toolbar issue please shared your working jsfiddle link or any other live website link.. we can better understand.

Comment: Google Chrome Toolbars works in a way that they include dynamic content onto the page with absolute positioning. Can you provide link to the said page?

Comment: I came across this as well!  It made a much bigger mess of my layout though.

Comment: We're getting this issue as well - elements that are positioned absolutely inside relatively positioned containers are suddenly thrown out of their proper position when the Ask toolbar is active.

Comment: @AndFinally wrapping everything inside a div wrapper fixed this for me

Comment: Thanks John - do you mean adding a relatively positioned wrapper div around your whole content?

Comment: Yes from what I can remember Ask is appended to the body

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Javascript snippet can disable ask toolbar in chrome. I hope this function spreads quickly!!

```
function removeAsk(){
    if(document.getElementById("apn-null-toolbar") != null){
        // mainMenu had a style change for its top positioning, returning it to normal
        // perhaps a function can be made which iterates over every element ask has changed
        document.getElementById("mainMenu").style.top = "-16px";
        // Just remove the iframe and style elements
        (elem=document.getElementById("apn-null-toolbar")).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        (elem=document.getElementById("apn-body-style")).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
```

Call this method after body onload

```
<body onload="removeAsk()">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Chrome extensions API for creating a toolbar so mentioned extension must have created it via content script. What it means is that for each page you open, CSS and JavaScript files are injected by this extension to create a DOM element within the page acting as a toolbar. Problem with this solution is that using the content script it is possible to mess up website look or even the way it works.

Comment: What a joke, so we are never going to be able to add a background-image to the `body` position top without wrapping everything in a pointless extra div

Comment: I'm not sure why do you care about people that have this extension installed? There are probably lots of poorly coded Chrome extensions that break layouts on some pages. There is no way to create a website that is protected from these extensions. And it doesn't make sense to try protecting your site from this in the first place. It is not your problem, it is an issue on the user side.

Comment: The extensions is automatically installed with some Adobe updates on Windows XP when the user doesn't turn off the checkbox and is hard to uninstall for some people.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same issue with the Ask Toolbar. I basically took out my positioning attributes and top/left/right/bottom 's and replaced with margins. Margin uses less space and it comes out cleaner.

Although i do agree, it's kind of ridiculous to accommodate for a toolbar because the end-user could have anything installed that breaks and gives your layout bugs. Even Skype extensions will break a layout just changing the phone number.

So there's not much you can do, but use margins and keep CSS to a minimum. Just my 2 cents. and if you have to use CSS then stick with margins.